# How to calcluate Compund interest in C#

Tags: c#, math

Hi there I have been trying to calcluate Compund interest. Its works with Math.Pow but I am not allowed to use math.pow but use for loop instead. Here is my code. Can i get a little help. thanks

```
        double amount;
        double interest;
        int years;
        double balance = 0;

        Console.WriteLine("Enter the Amount");
        amount = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Enter the Interest Rate");
        interest = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine()) / 100;

        Console.WriteLine("Enter number of Years");
        years = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        for (int i = 0; i <= years; i++)
        {
            balance = amount * Math.Pow((1 + interest), years);


        }

        {
            Console.WriteLine("Total Amount Balane is: {0}", balance);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

}

without pow

```
        double amount;
        double interest;
        int years;
        double balance = 0;

        Console.WriteLine("Enter the Amount");
        amount = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Enter the Interest Rate");
        interest = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine()) / 100;

        Console.WriteLine("Enter number of Years");
        years = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        for (int i = 0; i <= years; i++)
        {
            balance = amount * (1 + interest) ;


        }

        {
            Console.WriteLine("Total Amount Balane is: {0}", balance);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: What is wrong with your code so far, other than it uses Math.Pow?

Comment: I am not allowed to use Math.Pow. I need to use For Loop which calculates interest after every year

Comment: I smell schoolwork... try harder

Comment: Ok, have you attempted to do that? Yes, you have attempted _with_ the helper function. Now attempt _without_ it. Then ask us to help you finish it up.

Comment: Yup i have tried but it doesn't give the right value

Comment: Do you know how to do it by hand? If yes then transfer the steps into `C#`. If not, you have some reading to do. Your error is with the loop.

Comment: Looks suspect: `i = 0; i <= years`

Comment: so "without pow" basically means removing the pow function? and you expect it to give the same result?

Comment: This could be fixed with one + sign. Don't we have a site to help with homework stuff?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that each time you are calculating the interest from the initial `amount` 
Your loop logic is structured correctly but your calculation should be

```
balance = balance * (1 + interest);
```

so that each 'year' you also calculate the interest from the previous year and make that your new base.

Comment: The formula he has inside the loop in the first code snippet actually calculates the balance for the entire period. It's the first formula in the Wikipedia article about compound interest. It doesn't need to be looped - it gives the answer in one step.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_interest  My suspicion here is the person doesn't fully understand compound interest - this is a typical beginner mistake: coding on a problem you don't understand, thinking you'll "arrive" at the answer. This person needs a discussion, not an answer.

Comment: @LovepreetBrar you need to study and start doing your homework instead of asking the solutions here. (and you don't even care to accept the answers)